STM32F103 SPI Clock Signal is not generated
I am trying to communicate with a Winbond W25Q (16 MBit) chip with Standard SPI connection. I am using Keil to code and debug. It looks like I am unable to generate the clock signal for the SPI line. Here is the code I have written so far.
Note: I am doing it as bare metal and library is used.
#include "spi.h"
#include "globals.h"

SPI_Config_TypeDef SPIConfig[2];


void SPI_Init(SPI_TypeDef *SPIx, GPIO_TypeDef * CSPort, uint32_t CSPin) {
    // SCK => PA5
    // MISO => PA6
    // MSIO => PA7
    // NSS => PA4
    if(SPIx == SPI1){
        RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN;
        //CLK
        GPIO_Init(GPIOA, 5, GPIO_CNF_AF_OUTPUT_PP, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_50MHZ);
        //MISO
        GPIO_Init(GPIOA, 6, GPIO_CNF_INPUT_FLOATING, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);
        //MOSI
        GPIO_Init(GPIOA, 7, GPIO_CNF_AF_OUTPUT_PP, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_50MHZ);
        
        AFIO->MAPR &= ~AFIO_MAPR_SPI1_REMAP;
        
        //CS
        if(CSPort){
            SPIConfig[0].CSPort = CSPort;
            SPIConfig[0].CSPin = CSPin;
            //CS / NSS
            GPIO_Init(CSPort, CSPin, GPIO_CNF_GP_OUTPUT_PP, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_50MHZ);
        } else {
            SPIConfig[0].CSPort = NULL;
            SPIConfig[0].CSPin = 0;
            //CS / NSS
            GPIO_Init(GPIOA, 4, GPIO_CNF_AF_OUTPUT_PP, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_50MHZ);
        }
        
        RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN | RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN;
    } else {
        return;
    }
    
    //Mode: Master
    SPIx->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_MSTR;
    //Baud rate to (72MHz / 32 = ~ 2.25MHz)
    SPIx->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_BR_0;
    SPIx->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_BR_1;
    SPIx->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_BR_2;
    //MSB first
    SPIx->CR1 &= ~(SPI_CR1_LSBFIRST);
    //Full duplex (Transmit/Receive)
    SPIx->CR1 &= ~(SPI_CR1_RXONLY);
    //Data format 8-bit
    SPIx->CR1 &= ~(SPI_CR1_DFF);
    
    SPIx->CR1 &= ~(SPI_CR1_CPOL);
    SPIx->CR1 &= ~(SPI_CR1_CPHA);
    
    if(CSPort) {
        SPIx->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSI;
        SPIx->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSM;
    } else {
        SPIx->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_SSM;
        SPIx->CR2 |= SPI_CR2_SSOE;
    }
    
    if(CSPort) {
        //SPI Enable
        SPIx->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
        //Clear initial flags
        (void)SPIx->SR;
    }
}

uint32_t SPI_SendAndReceive(SPI_TypeDef * SPIx, uint8_t * data, uint32_t dataLength, uint8_t * buffer, uint32_t bufferLength, uint32_t timeout) {
    SPI_CSLow(SPIx);
    uint32_t counter = 0;
    uint32_t startAt = getTickCount();
    while(counter < dataLength)
    {
        while (!(SPIx->SR & SPI_SR_TXE) && (getTickCount() - startAt) <= timeout) { }
        if(getTickCount() - startAt > timeout) break;
        SPIx->DR = *(data++);
        counter++;
    }
    
    /*Wait for the TXE bit to set in the Status Register*/
    while (!(SPIx->SR & SPI_SR_TXE) && (getTickCount() - startAt) <= timeout) { }

    /*Wait for the BSY bit to reset in the Status Register*/
    while ((SPIx->SR & SPI_SR_BSY) && (getTickCount() - startAt) <= timeout) { }
    
    if(counter == dataLength) {                 
        counter = 0;
        do {
            while (!(SPIx->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE) && (getTickCount() - startAt) <= timeout) { }
            if(getTickCount() - startAt > timeout) break;
            *(buffer++) = SPIx->DR;
            counter++;
        } while (counter < bufferLength);
    
    }

    SPI_CSHigh(SPIx);
    
    return counter == bufferLength ? 1 : 0;
}

void SPI_Send(SPI_TypeDef * SPIx, uint8_t * data)
{
    SPI_CSLow(SPIx);
    while(data)
    {
         /*Wait for the TXE bit to set in the Status Register*/
         /*This will indicate that the transmit buffer is empty*/
         while (!(SPIx->SR & SPI_SR_TXE)) {};
         /* Write the data to the Data Register */
         SPIx->DR = *data++;
    }
    
    /*Wait for the TXE bit to set in the Status Register*/
    while (!(SPIx->SR & SPI_SR_TXE)) {};

    /*Wait for the BSY bit to reset in the Status Register*/
    while ((SPIx->SR & SPI_SR_BSY)) {};

    SPI_CSHigh(SPIx);
}

static void SPI_CSLow(SPI_TypeDef *SPIx){
    SPI_Config_TypeDef spiConfig = SPIx == SPI1 ? SPIConfig[0] : SPIConfig[1];
    if(spiConfig.CSPort != NULL){
        GPIO_Reset(spiConfig.CSPort, spiConfig.CSPin);
    } else {
        SPIx->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
    }
}

static void SPI_CSHigh(SPI_TypeDef *SPIx){
    SPI_Config_TypeDef spiConfig = SPIx == SPI1 ? SPIConfig[0] : SPIConfig[1];
    if(spiConfig.CSPort != NULL){
        GPIO_Set(spiConfig.CSPort, spiConfig.CSPin);
    } else {
        SPIx->CR1 &= ~(SPI_CR1_SPE);
    }
}


Screenshot of the GPIO-A Config Register

Screenshot of logic analyzer:


OK, so does it just not generate a clock? Or is there some other problem? Have you debugged the code in any way? Does it hit the timeout or hang somewhere else, or just no signals come out?

Oops, it was the wrong GPIO config

Bad mistake, the GPIO configuration was wrong. Actually last 2 parameters for GPIO_Init were swapped. Fixing them, the system generated the clock. I'll go ahead and try to do the SPI data transactions now..
